# Is this possible to make button to open new window in other frame?

Tags: figma

I'm trying to make a table with windows like "filter, add new, edit" in one column next to my table. Buttons are in my table. Is it possible to make the buttons which open edit, filter and add new next to my table?

Everything is prototype and table is with 3 categories and it's possible to change the content in the tables by buttons. I tried to make this by prototype but always opens like "move in" etc which opens in the same window what table. I need to make this table to minimize the width. Is it possible?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about programming.

Comment: Not able to understand. keep sentence short and self explanatory.